# Recurrence tick box in formulas for Activities

Tags: validation

I'm trying to write a validation rule for Activities the will use the output result on the **"Recurrence"** tick box, **"Create Recurring Series of Tasks"**, to give an error on the Status field.

Some thing like:

If Activity Create Recurring Series true and
Status not equals planned
Error = true (No save allow)
If Activity Create Recurring Series true and 
Status equals planned
Error = false (Save allow)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you could do this using a validation rule because the flag 'IsRecurrence' is not visible when you try to create a validation rule on Task object.
But you could do this by a Trigger before insert on Task and check if the Task.IsRecurrence = true and the status doesn't equal to 'planned'

```
trigger TaskBeforeInsert on Task (before insert) 
{
    for(Task t : Trigger.new)
        if(t.IsRecurrence && t.Status != 'planned')
            t.addError('Error');
}
```

This code is juste to show you how to do it, for better code organisation you have to move it an Apex Class.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello melmoussaoui, that did it. I created a trigger on task and another on events to have this logic running. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that I helped!